# Communicating iOS chat service with a web chat service

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm searching for a cross-platform chat service that supports mobile (Android and iOS), and Desktop. I've looked into a few sites that offer chat services, but none of them seem to be what I'm looking for in terms of features. So I've decided to try to create an iOS application that will connect to a service that we will use for the desktop version.

That was just a bit of background info, but here's the question:

I am creating a url request in order to send information to the server that will handle and store my url request like so:

```
-(IBAction)clickedSendButton:(id)sender
{
    urlReq = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/mobile/PrivateChatMsgSending/?sid=%@&skey=%@&rid=%@&msg=%@",domain,((ApplicationAppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).loggedProfileID,((ApplicationAppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).loggedSessionID,receipientProfileId,txtFldChat.text];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlReq stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLRequest *urlrequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    connection = [[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlrequest delegate:self] autorelease]; 
    [self ShowIndicatorView:@"Sending..."];

}
```

So would I be able to pass these parameters to my php script on the server side all while being compatible with my desktop version? Is there anything within my application that could potentially inhibit my user's from receiving messages from desktop users? What might be a better solution to creating a multi-platform messaging service?

Comment: If you want to do this in realtime, you might have a much easier time with WebSockets.

Comment: Please change your title to accurately describe the question. The title you have is for an off-topic subject.